# Vscode syntax highlighting completely broken

Tags: visual-studio-code

Syntax highlighting in VSCode looks like the attached image in this c/c++ project. I have another project where it works absolutely fine

[image]

Has anyone seen this before?

I'm using the WSL, microsoft c/c++, git graph, git history and synopsys extensions if it matters. The git highlighting is also missing entirely

Comment: In the bottom-right corner the current language should be indicated, does it correctly how C / C++? If it's not that, then it's semantic highlighting misbehaving (try disabling it in the settings).

Comment: I do indeed have c++ selected for the interpreted language